# What is "()=>{}" in js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I searched for

> "()=>{} in js"

on Google 
But it's not displaying relative results
What is it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Search for empty arrow functions, to improve your results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=>` is a shortcut for an anonymous function.  So that's just a function that does nothing.  equivalent to:

```
function () { }
```

Comment: ...except [lexical context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Relation_with_strict_mode).